# Split single column in csv files using python

Tags: python, csv

This is the data inside one of a column in CSV file.

```
91.1 [69.6-118.8]
93.9 [74.5-118.3]
96.7 [79.1-118.2]
99.5 [83.8-118.5]
102.3 [88.1-119.3]
105.0 [92.0-120.6]
```

What I need to do is split this into two column.

```
91.1             [69.6-118.8]
93.9             [74.5-118.3]
96.7             [79.1-118.2]
99.5             [83.8-118.5]
102.3            [88.1-119.3]
105.0            [92.0-120.6]
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use `open.readlines()` and `str.split()`

```
arr =[]

lines = open("my.csv").readlines()

for line in lines:
    arr.append(line.split())

print(arr)
```